androidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libreactnativejni.so" not found
On .apk file, it's can open app as expected
however on protected .apk file from Dexguard
when I try to open app, I got error (my app crashed)
androidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libreactnativejni.so" not found
on dexguard-protected.pro
this is my config
-keep class **.so
-keepdirectories lib/**
-keep class **.libreactnativejni { *; }

how to fixed it?
I'm already check on .zip file of .apk
I found libreactnativejni.so on normal .apk but not in protected .apk file

I had the same crash in my app too. I upgraded my app to latest react native version and the error was gone. Check https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35374

@RohitAggarwal what's your react native version?, I'm using   "react-native": "^0.75.4" but error still existed

I'm already fix this issue by
on /android/app/build.gradle please make sure about this setting
 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro", 'dexguard-release.pro'

and on rule file
add -keepresourcefiles lib/**
at first, I can not use keepresourcefiles because my proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile wrong (I was adding dexguard-protected.pro because I thought I have to add it too)
